# How to find how long my rake task is taking

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.0.10 . I am using mac.

I tried this

```
time  rake spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

Then I tried

```
time (rake spec/models/user_spec.rb)
```

This one took longer but I did not see my test output.

What is the right way to figure out how long my rake is taking.

Comment: Please delete this question. instead of rake I should have typed rspec

Comment: I requested to delete it because this question does not make SO a richer place. There is no need for anyone to see this question.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to time any command using 'time' and run your single test directly using the ruby interpreter:

```
time ruby spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

Comment: Is there any way to know the run time using any tool like new relic??